# Calculating % of CPU time consumed by a process on the tiva 5 series ARM M4F core microcontroller

Tags: cpu-usage, rtos

I am designing an RTOS for the tiva 5 series microcontroller and I am supporting basic linux commands like ps. I need to calculate the percentage of cpu time consumed by every process in the RTOS as I display that as a result of the ps command.

What is the best way forward?

Answer (score 0):

In real time, any way should sample the program counter value at regular intervals.

The quicker the samples the better the results.